# C++ overloading bracket [] operator get & set with different return types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, operator-overloading, operators

I'm trying to overload the [] operator for a class that I created with different return types for the getter and setter.

I want the setter to return a reference to a another class instance, which is happening fine at the moment, the problem is that I want the getter to return a char, but in my main when i'm assigning char c = object[5] it's calling the setter instead of the getter and returning the wrong return type.

That how it looks in my code:

Board.h

```
const char& operator[](Board_Node index) const;
Board_Node& operator[](Board_Node index);
```

Board.cpp

```
const char& Board::operator[](Board_Node index) const
{
    int boardIndex = index.i * _boardSize + index.j;
    if (boardIndex < 0 || boardIndex >= _board.size())
    {
        throw IllegalCoordinateException(index.i, index.j);
    }
    return _board[index.i * _boardSize + index.j].token;
}

Board_Node & Board::operator[](Board_Node index)
{
    int boardIndex = index.i * _boardSize + index.j;
    if (boardIndex < 0 || boardIndex >= _board.size())
    {
        throw IllegalCoordinateException(index.i, index.j);
    }
    return _board[index.i * _boardSize + index.j];
}
```

main.cpp

```
char c = board1[{1, 2}]; cout << c << endl;
```

That line results in error: no suitable conversion function from "Board_Node" to "char" exists.

Already tried all forms with const everywhere and nothing worked.

Appericiate any help, thank you!

Comment: Is `board1` `const`?

Comment: Just do not use `operator[]` but regular method(s)

Comment: Unless `Board_Node` is implicitly convertible to `char` you're looking for trouble with this design.

Comment: Note that the return type has *no* effect on overload resolution at all. The compiler won't look at what you are doing with the result to choose an overload.

Comment: I'm using operator[] because the main was given by the professor at the university which made me use it
It is basically a Tic Tac Toe board.. i used vector of board_noad which is another custom class containing x,y and token to represent the board itself

Comment: A quick and dirty way of getting this to work would be to use `static_cast<const Board&>(_board)[{1,2}];` to force the `const` overload to be used.

Comment: Having different return types on `const` qualifying overloads of `operator[]` sounds like a recipe for destruction.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the overloaded functions getters and setters based on whether an object is `const` or non-`const` is not appropriate.

The non-`const` version of the overload is given higher priority if the object is not `const`.

I suggest adding an explicitly named getter function, which can use the overloaded `operator[]` function.

```
char get(Board_Node index) const
{
   return (*this)[index];
}
```

---

As a matter of good practice, it will be better to change the return type of the `const` version of the `operator[]` function to return `Board_Node const&`.

```
Board_Node const& operator[](Board_Node index) const;
Board_Node& operator[](Board_Node index);
```

That will allow you to extract other information from the corresponding `Board_Node`, not just a `char`.

With that, you won't need the 'get`function. You'll have to change usage of the`operator[]` function a bit.

```
char c = board1[{1, 2}].token;
cout << c << endl;
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, My impression is that the OP wants to simplify the return value for today's needs without worrying about tomorrow's needs.